# Did the Pakistan government accidentally cause YouTube to become unusable in 2008?

Tags: internet, government, networks

From the [source of all knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Google#cite_note-202)

> On February 22, 2008, Pakistan Telecommunications Authority (PTA)
>   attempted to block regional access to YouTube following a government
>   order. The attempt inadvertently caused a worldwide YouTube blackout
>   that took 2 hours to correct.

Sadly the reference link is broken. How can a websites with presumably servers around the world be accidentally taken out? I'm interested in the technical details of what the authorities did that disabled YouTube.

Comment: it's not impossible, you just need to tinker with the [border gateway protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) and it wouldn't be the first time that got screwed up

Comment: The source now is from http://www.macworld.co.uk/news/apple/pakistan-causes-worldwide-youtube-blackout-20536/.

Answer (score 10):

I remember that event!

The European IP Network's Network Coordination Centre (RIPE NCC - *the acronym makes more sense in French*) issued [a case-study about the incident](http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/news/industry-developments/youtube-hijacking-a-ripe-ncc-ris-case-study).

> On Sunday, 24 February 2008, Pakistan Telecom (AS17557) started an unauthorised announcement of the prefix 208.65.153.0/24. One of Pakistan Telecom's upstream providers, PCCW Global (AS3491) forwarded this announcement to the rest of the Internet, which resulted in the hijacking of YouTube traffic on a global scale.

It contains the technical details on the IP range hijacking.

Comment: I remember I was logging into my friends facebook while he was in america, is it possible?